# VSTO document level customiztion

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, vsto, office-addins

VSTO document level Addins works only for that document which are saved in the system?
its not works for the document which open from Mail attachement ?

Answer (score 1):

Document-level customizations are designed to work with a single document in a single application domain. They are not designed for cross-document communication. You have to develop a Application-level customization to deal with documents which open from Mail attachment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zcfbd2sk.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398248(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe the document will not work without its assembly been sent down. Check the How Customization Work with Microsoft Office Applications? section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/zcfbd2sk.aspx).

Another option would be to place the assembly in the shared location. So the recipient opens the document the assembly will be loaded from the shared location.